# The approximation formula $\left|\alpha -\frac{p}{q}\right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, approximation

I have seen a result about the approximation of irrational numbers and want to find its proof.

> Suppose $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then there are infinitely many integers $p,q$ with $(p,q)=1$ such that 
>   $$\left|\alpha -\frac{p}{q}\right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.$$

Is there a name attached to this theorem? Where can I find the proof of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29), look at refs in the link.

Comment: @achillehui : do you think it requires many steps for being convinced of it once we know this inequality http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818499/a-step-on-the-proof-of-liouvilles-theorem-on-approximation/1818517#1818517 for algebraic numbers ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think so, the direction of inequality is different. In the Liouville's theorem, it gives a lower bound to how close an algebraic irrational number can be approximated by rational numbers. In the Hurwitz's theorem, it is an upper bound for arbitrary irrationals.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem in your question is known as **Hurwitz's Theorem**. It was first stated by A. Hurwitz in 1891 in the article "Ueber die angenäherte Darstellung der Irrationalzahlen durch rationale Brüche" (***Eng***. On the approximation of irrational numbers by rational numbers), Math. Ann. XXXIX, pp. 279-284 (1891).

Hurwitz's article can be found here: https://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:23.0222.02, although the paper is in German.